# Looking for a virtual "tally counter"

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation

I run Ubuntu 20.04 and am looking for a tally counter software (can't figure out how to look for it with the proper keywords).

Say I am watching a video with people walking, I would like to press on a key or click for every person I see and get the total number in the end. It does not need to be more elaborate than that.

Any software or a simple trick that could help me?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried searching for "Linux tally counter"? I come up with at least one that claims to run on Linux.

Comment: @Sebastian If you are referring to [this](https://www.onworks.net/software/app-my-tally-counter), I can't get it to work...

Comment: Yes, that's the only one I found so far too. It wouldn't be too hard to code one though, I would almost be tempted to give it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I whipped something up quickly as a weekend project.

Does [this](https://github.com/skauertz/QCounter) look useful?

[image: QCounter main window]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed

Comment: Cool...glad it could help.